# How to make a macOS menu text dyamic?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to make the text of a menu item (in a Mac Application) dynamic like this:

```swift
@main
struct VeyBoardApp: App {
    @State var optionsHidden: Bool = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.sidebar) {
                Button(optionsHidden ? "Show Options" : "Hide Options") {
                    print(self.optionsHidden) // correctly alternates between true and false
                    self.optionsHidden.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect the button item to change "Show Options" and "Hide options", but its stays on "Hide options". How to do this?

Comment: You could achieve this within a custom `CommandMenu`: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/11/24/commands-in-swiftui/