# SwiftUI option key alternate menu items on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

In many macOS apps, if you open a menu from the main menubar, you can press the option key to change some of the items.

For example in Safari, I can open the *File* menu, and there is a "Close Tab" item. Pressing option changes it to "Close Other Tabs".

Is there a way to do this with SwiftUI?

I know how to create basic menus, but I don't see a way to detect the option key.

I think in AppKit you use `NSMenuItem`'s `isAlternate` property.

```swift
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { 
            ...
        }.commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) {
                Button { newFolder() } label: { Text("New Folder") }
                   .keyboardShortcut("n")
                ...
            }        
        }
```

**Update to Question**

I've tried a few more things, and run into two problems.

1. I can connect a custom object to the end of the `NSResponder` chain, and the system will call its `flagsChanged` method when the user presses the option key. However, it will *not* call this method when a menu is open.
2. Even if I find a way to observe the option key while the menu is open, changing state used to build a `CommandMenu` causes the menu to disappear, not rebuild and stay open.

```swift
var body: some Commands {
   // If the `isOptionDown` property changes when this menu is open,
   // SwiftUI doesn't change the menu, it simply closes it.
   // That's not how macOS apps usually behave.
   CommandGroup(replacing: .pasteboard) {
      Button(...)
      if optionKeyWatcher.isOptionDown {
          Button(...)
      } else {
          Button(...)
      }
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no SwiftUI native way to even react on classic keydown events. For that there is a workaround here: https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-handle-keydown-in-swiftui-for-macos/  Maybe you can use this to change the Menu item based on a @State var changing.

Comment: or maybe not ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679628/how-to-make-a-macos-menu-text-dyamic